# mysql multiple values in 2 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with those fields:
`phID`, `ProductID`

The `phID` is the pharmacy id and the `ProductID` is the product id.

- One pharmacy has multiple products
- 1 product is to multiple pharmacies

Example:

```
phID    ProductID
-----------------
1001    9
1001    10
1001    11
1004    9
1004    12
1004    14
1004    11
```

The query that I want is so I can get all the `phID` that has the same product.
I have this query:

```
SELECT phID, ProductID
FROM ph_pd
WHERE ProductID IN (9,10,11)
```

I want the results to be

```
1001 9
1004 9
1001 11
1004 11
```

or just

```
1001
1004
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021cd/5
I made this from LolCoder answer
and i think is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get distinct phID which are fall under the certain productID, you have to use DISTINCT...

```
  SELECT distinct phID FROM ph_pd WHERE ProductID IN (9,10,11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
SELECT p.phID , p.ProductID FROM ph_pd p
WHERE (select count(*) from ph_pd where ProductID = p.ProductID) >= 2
ORDER BY ProductID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  phID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   productID IN (9,10,11)
GROUP   BY phID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT productID) = 2 -- since there are two stores
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe0b/3)